# How can i find the number of times string1 present in string2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
str2 ='welcome to sql server. Sql server is a product of Microsoft sql' 
str1 = 'sql'
```

How can i find the number of times str1 present in str2. Please help me finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @Str1 varchar(10)
declare @Str2 varchar(100)

set @Str1 = 'sql'
set @Str2 ='welcome to sql server. Sql server is a product of Microsoft sql' 

select (datalength(@Str2) - datalength(replace(@Str2, @Str1, ''))) / datalength(@Str1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(10) 
SET @str1 = 'sql'
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(100) 
SET @str2 = 'welcome to sql server. Sql server is a product of Microsoft sql' 

SELECT (DATALENGTH(@str2) - DATALENGTH(REPLACE(@str2, @str1, ''))) / DATALENGTH(@str1)
```

This is just removing all instances of @str1 from @str2 (using REPLACE), comparing the difference in length to the original value of @str2. This gives the total number of characters that have been removed, so you divide by the length of @str1 to find out how many instances where removed.

Comment: +1 to you :). There is a corner case where yours and mine version will have different output. It is when there are more than 3 spaces left at the end of the modified string.

Comment: what can we do in such case ?

Comment: @Amrutha Perumal – Use `datalength` instead of `len`.

Comment: Yes, as Mikael says - it would be better to use DATALENGTH. Updated.

Comment: @Amrutha: If you are using `DATALENGTH` on an `nvarchar`, divide the result of `DATALENGTH` by 2, because in `nvarchar` every character takes 2 bytes of memory, instead of 1 like in `varchar`. (And it's the bytes that DATALENGTH returns, not chars.)

Answer (score 0):

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) is what you are looking for

Comment: That finds the location of the first instance, not the overall number of instances.

Comment: yep, it needs to be in the loop with a counter

Comment: if i make use of patindex() or charindex() we will get the first occurence of pattren mentioned. But i want how many times the pattren is repeating in the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about using COUNT and GROUP BY ('sql') ?

Comment: I tried below while(PATINDEX('%'+@str1+'%',@s)>0)
begin
      set @s = REPLACE(@s,substring(@s,PATINDEX('%'+@str1+'%',@s),len(@str1)),'')
      set @c=@c +1
end